# Best way to implement autocomplete with sql

Tags: sql, database, autocomplete

I know this question has been up before but that was like three years ago and that's a lifetime :).

I'm using the twitter-bootstrap typeahead for autocomplete against mysql db with php, it works good right now. But I hit the db with a query every key-event, it doesn't feel like a good solution for a large scale application.

What's the best aproach here? Im thinking about memcache, but this is a dynamic db that will grow, how do I make sure that new information in the db get's cached to? I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Just because you put it in bold does not make it true.  This is a case of fixing a problem you don't have.  Implement a solution see if you have a problem, if not move on to something else.

Comment: No I don't have a problem right now but don't you see that there will be problems later with high web traffic. I asked the question because I couln't find any recent answers or articles about it. And I think that there's is more people out there other than me that are curious about the 'correct' approach with autocomplete against a db.

Answer (score 1):

On Feb 2013 Twitter released **typeahead** (is not the bootstrap one),
it is s a powerful opensource lib for autocomplete, and one of his feature is:

> Rate-limits network requests to lighten the load

I suggest you to give try.

Useful links:

http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/examples/

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

http://engineering.twitter.com/2013/02/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me.html

Answer (score 0):

For autocomplete it's possible use trigram matching.

Also you can use specialized fulltext search engines like Solr/Lucene or Sphinx.

Another alternative: switch to postgresql and use pg_trgm extension.